# How to (Full)Simplify real expression so intermediate terms are also real?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

```
t[r_] = (d*Sqrt[2*g*r - (2*g*r^2)/d])/(2*g*r) - (g*r^2*Log[-(g*r^2)])/
  (2*Sqrt[2]*(-((g*r^2)/d))^(3/2)) + 
 (g*r^2*Log[g*r^2 - (2*g*r^3)/d + Sqrt[2]*r*Sqrt[-((g*r^2)/d)]*
      Sqrt[2*g*r - (2*g*r^2)/d]])/(2*Sqrt[2]*(-((g*r^2)/d))^(3/2))

conds = {g>0, r>0, d>r}
```

Under the `conds` above, `t[r]` is always real. It contains terms like
`Log[-(g*r^2)]` which aren't real under `conds`, but it turns out the
complex numbers all cancel out.

However, I want to "publish" this formula, so I'd like a
simplification that doesn't have complex numbers even as intermediate
terms. Some failed attempts:

```
$Version

9.0 for Linux x86 (32-bit) (November 20, 2012)

(* the most obvious still contains Log[-(g*r^2)] *)

Simplify[t[r], conds] // InputForm

((-I/2)*(2*Sqrt[r*(-d + r)] + d*Log[-(g*r^2)] - 
   d*Log[(g*r^2*(d - 2*r + 2*Sqrt[r*(-d + r)]))/d]))/(Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[g/d]*r)

(* the second most obvious explicitly contains I *)

FullSimplify[t[r], conds] // InputForm

(d*(2*Sqrt[(d - r)*r] + d*(Pi - I*Log[d] + 
     I*Log[d - 2*r + (2*I)*Sqrt[(d - r)*r]])))/(2*Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[d*g]*r)

(* redundantly adding Element[{r,g,d}, Reals] as a condition; note
that the answer contains Sign[r] even though r>0 guarantees Sign[r] ==
1 *)

FullSimplify[t[r], {conds, Element[{r,g,d}, Reals]}] // InputForm

    g*r*(Log[-g] - Log[g - (2*g*r)/d + (2*Sqrt[-(g/d)]*Sqrt[(g*(d - r)*r)/d])/
         Sign[r]]))*Sign[r])/(2*Sqrt[2]*(-(g/d))^(3/2)*r^2)

(* playing Mathematica's game, lets make Sign[r] = 1 *)

FullSimplify[t[r], {conds, Element[{r,g,d}, Reals]}] /.
 Sign[r] -> 1 // InputForm

-(2*Sqrt[-(g/d)]*Sqrt[(g*(d - r)*r^3)/d] + 
   g*r*(Log[-g] - Log[g - (2*g*r)/d + 2*Sqrt[-(g/d)]*Sqrt[(g*(d - r)*r)/d]]))/
 (2*Sqrt[2]*(-(g/d))^(3/2)*r^2)

(* above contains a negative square root AND a negative log, so lets
try this (note that the Sign[r] simplification only works if it's done
after the other two): *)

FullSimplify[t[r], {conds, Element[{r,g,d}, Reals]}] /. 
 {Sqrt[x_]*Sqrt[y_] -> Sqrt[x*y], Log[x_]-Log[y_] -> Log[x/y]} /.
 {Sign[r] -> 1} // InputForm

-(2*Sqrt[-((g^2*(d - r)*r^3)/d^2)] + 
   g*r*Log[-(g/(g - (2*g*r)/d + 2*Sqrt[-(g/d)]*Sqrt[(g*(d - r)*r)/d]))])/
 (2*Sqrt[2]*(-(g/d))^(3/2)*r^2)
```

That's about as far as I got before giving up. The `(-(g/d))^(3/2)` is
particularly difficult to get rid of, even with `{x_^(3/2) ->
x*Sqrt[x]}`.

Although it's probably not relevant, I derived the function to compute
the landing time of an object at distance d on a planet with radius r
and surface gravity g:

```
sol = DSolve[{x''[t] == -g/(x[t]/r)^2}, x[t], t] 

t1[x_] = -sol[[1,1,1]]-C[2] /. x[t] -> x 

(* solving for constants *) 

c1sol = Solve[Simplify[1/t1'[d]] == 0, C[1]][[1]] 

(* above gives C[1] -> -2*g*r^2/d *) 

t2[x_] = t1[x] /. c1sol 

c2sol = Solve[t2[d] == 0, C[2]][[1]] 

t[x_] = t2[x] /. c2sol 

t[r]
```

The function `t[x]` gives the time when the object is at distance `x`
from the planet's center, so `t[r]` represents the time when the
object hits the planets surface.

Even more details: https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/QUORA/bc-1ly.m and https://www.quora.com/unanswered/How-long-would-an-object-fall-to-Earth-from-1-light-year-distance-if-other-bodies-didnt-perturb-the-trajectory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$Version

(*  "10.4.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 11, 2016)"  *)

t[r_] = (d*Sqrt[2*g*r - (2*g*r^2)/d])/(2*g*r) - (g*r^2*
      Log[-(g*r^2)])/(2*Sqrt[2]*(-((g*r^2)/d))^(3/2)) + (g*r^2*
      Log[g*r^2 - (2*g*r^3)/d + 
        Sqrt[2]*r*Sqrt[-((g*r^2)/d)]*Sqrt[2*g*r - (2*g*r^2)/d]])/(2*
      Sqrt[2]*(-((g*r^2)/d))^(3/2));

conds = {g > 0, r > 0, d > r};

Assuming[conds, 
 t[r] // Simplify //
   ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] & //
  Simplify]

(*  (Sqrt[d/g]*(d*Pi + 
         2*Sqrt[(d - r)*r] - 
         d*ArcTan[d - 2*r, 
             2*Sqrt[(d - r)*r]]))/
   (2*Sqrt[2]*r)  *)
```

Comment: Worked on my version too. Thanks!